# Turning web app to Android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, web

I have an online store (like [PC WORLD](http://www.pcworld.co.uk/gbuk/index.html)) and I want to create a Android app of this store, too.

The back-end of this online store is written by PHP & MySQL Database. So all of the data is stored in MySQL Database.

So what is the best way to retrieve information from remote MySQL server to my Android app?

Best regards,
Julius

Comment: Have you thought of creating a website for mobiles instead of creating an application? Via a website you can reach more people than via an app.

Comment: Yes, I have thought about this. But... Knowing the variety of different mobile phones I think it would be hard to support most of them.

Comment: As long as you keep your website simple it won't be hard to support all of them. You can easily do this by using library frameworks such as jQuery which takes care of the diversity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a web service or some sort of API for your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have also thought about using API and I think it would be the best way do retrieve information from remote server to my mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using your current web site and just creating a web view app?  In other words just creating a web browser window minus the address bar, and other controls?  You could create one custom webpage then all you would be doing in the native app language is the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

To retrive data from mysql the best way is create your web as android app or simply convert this web application to an android app by using www.web2apk.com.
This site will create an apk file of your web application. So you dont need to make any new database for android it will automatically retrive from same database.
You dont need to include any service for that.